# how to add a fixed position Box on left side of each post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want help in Assigning a content on left side of the Box 
Example Please see this JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fgRRw/

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:10px;   
    margin-left:25%;
    color:#000000;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    opacity:0.95;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    content: "+";
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    left: -30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But the Content of the CSS how should i click it i mean i need to keep different buttons like that

To short the answer

For each post on the page left side i want to display a box

[image]

Please help me with this .

Comment: not clear what you are asking....please try elaborating or rephrasing!

Comment: Actually let me explain what i wanted to ask is i have a custom made blog i want to display date and other things like social media buttons on the left side if the each post like the image on the top .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this look:

HTML:

```
<div id="main"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:10px;   
    margin-left:25%;
    color:#000000;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    opacity:0.95;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
#appended {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    background: orange;
    color: #fff; top: 10px;
    border-radius: 0;
    left: -30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#main').before('<div id="appended" onclick="someFunction()">+</div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fgRRw/29/

EDIT:

Added some more HTML to demonstrate multiple posts. Changed the CSS a bit because I wouldn't recommend you capture both `divs` with the first declaration. Added an implementation of `someFunction()` in order to show how it works.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/fgRRw/35/

Comment: WOW Thanks a lot :) that helps me alot :) thanks Alternatex , but small question, i have multiple posts like a blog in a page so for each page there will be different ID i want to click on that + so the action takes place for that particular post  how can we implement that functionality

Comment: @nani Check my updated answer. If it works for you accept the answer and if you have more questions I'd recommend opening a new question because this one has moved beyond its initial issue.

Comment: Thanks Alternatex :) this helps thanks alot